# Mysql - count results and display in descending order

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I want to query the table to get every `referer` and count duplicates and display each unique referrer and the number of times each unique referrer is recorded in the table. I'm a beginner with sql and php so any help in the right direction would be great :)

```
$ref=$icdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM url_log WHERE u = '".$dom."'");
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you run & customise the query in a mysql tool like [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php), or [HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com/) (great freeware tools) to see the results it gives.

It's difficult to give a precise answer without knowing what fields are in your table, but you could try;

```
SELECT u, COUNT(*) AS c FROM url_log GROUP BY u
```